# Add ajax parameters from onstart function

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, primefaces

A have primefaces commandButton with actionListener. On page I also have few dialogs, some of them are opened and others are closed. I need to dynamically find first closed dialog, call actionListener method, and pass parameters to that method with information which dialog is first closed. I use that information to update that dialog, and to call show() method to open dialog. I think that only possible place for that is onstart method, but I can't find the way to pass ajax parameter from onstart method. Is there any solution for this?

I'm using Primefaces 3.4, JSF 2.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correct, you want to pass the value hold in a JavaScript variable along with the form submit as well. Easiest would be to set it as value of the HTML representation of a `<h:inputHidden>` component.

Given this JSF

```
<h:form id="form">
    <h:inputHidden id="hidden" value="#{bean.hidden}" />
    ...
</h:form>
```

and this JS

```
var some = "some value";
```

you can set it by JS as follows

```
document.getElementById("form:hidden").value = some;
```

or, given that you're using PrimeFaces, by jQuery

```
$("#form\\:hidden").val(some);
```

Inside the JSF action method, it's just directly available as `hidden` property.

Comment: Yes, it can be done like that, and for now I will use that solution. This is somehow specific situation. I have datatable and I want to allow user to open dialogs with details of some entries. I can just find out from the javascript whick dialog is closed, and set hidden field on that value. In this moment I put the hiddent field. Thank your BalusC on you time.

Comment: Can't you just perform the job on click of dialog close button itself?

Comment: What I saw, while watching the code changes on primefaces is that they added cfg parameter to onstart functions. That parameter should be same parameter which is used for low level AjaxRequest function, and I can set update or process fields and some other parameters, and it works. But it is not possible to set params field. Maybe it is bug. See [link](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=3891), and [link](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/source/detail?r=7347)

Comment: On dialog close event just don't to what I want. For example, user can open 4 details, which means that dialogs 1, 2, 3 and 4 are opened. If he open one more detail, than dialog 5 will be opened. Than he can close dialogs 1, 3 and 5. I just need to find first "free" dialog fore use. Maybe I can hold some structure in javascript to follow this use case, but it is more easy to just find first dialog with some easy jQuery selector.